# How do I diagnose and fix breakpoints that Xcode cannot resolve?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, xcode13

Every now and then Xcode 13.3.1 (and 13.3) will fail to resolve breakpoints. It seems limited to the project but won't work until I have fully cloned the project.

Other projects - same machine, same time - will work as expected. No changes appear within Git.

It looks like this in Xcode

[image: Issue]

All the usual tricks have been applied:

- restart Xcode
- restart simulator/device
- clean
- delete Derived Data
- deleted breakpoints, and re-added
- run `breakpoint list` while paused

I'm keen to know how to diagnose, fix, and ideally prevent this occurring.

Comment: Still having the same exactly issue with XCode 13.3.1
Macos 12.3.1

Comment: I was beginning to think int was just me @KwnstantinosNikoloutsos ;) I tend to cloning and starting over from scratch helps, which makes me think there's an artefact somewhere. Only, my project is so big that a full File Merge is too large to help me find the differences.